# React / Генератор input

Tags: javascript, reactjs

У меня есть функция генерирующая input:

```
 const [addInput, setAddInput] = useState([]); 

 const exampleInput = (value) => {
    setAddInput([
        ...addInput,
        <input key={inputUuid}
               type='text'
               className='input'
               name={inputUuid}
               value={value}
        />
    ])
};
```

inputUuid - некое уникальное значение.

Используется она в функции, которая срабатывает по onClick:

```
function expamle(arrExample) {
    arrExample.forEach(item => {
        exampleInput(item);
    });
}
```

в arrExample приходит массив строк, например ['12', '1234', и т.д.]

Рисуются input:

```
<div>
    {addInput.map(item => item)}
</div>
```

Но рисуется только 1 input  с передаваемыми данными.
Просьба подсказать, что я делаю не так.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так проще

```
const [addInput, setAddInput] = useState([]);
//arrExample === ['12', '1234', и т.д.]
function expamle(arrExample) {
    setAddInput(previous=>[...previous, ...arrExample]);
}
return <>
        {addInput.map(value =>
               <input key={inputUuid}
               type='text'
               className='input'
               name={inputUuid}
               value={value}/>
        )}
       </>
```

А твоя функция не работает потому, что `setAddInput` работает асинхронно, а forEach синхронно. `forEach` всю обойму выстрелит, пока первый `setAddInput` только разогреваеться. Поэтому `addInput` будет `[]` в `forEach`

Comment: Да, спасибо, теперь ок!

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html почитай